# Working around rust's double borrow error in this pattern

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am writing a gameboy emulator and I have this function:

```rust
pub fn execute_classic_instruction(&mut self, opcode: u8) -> u64 {
    match opcode {
        0x31 => self.load_word_immediate_into_reg(&mut self.registers.sp),
        _ => unimplemented!(
            "Unimplemented opcode: 0x{:X} at PC=0x{:X}",
            opcode,
            self.registers.pc.value() - 1
        ),
    }
}
```

When opcode 0x31 is next it executes this:

```rust
pub fn load_word_immediate_into_reg<F>(&mut self, register: &mut Register) -> u64 {
    let value = self.mmu.read_word(self.registers.pc.value());
    self.registers.pc.add(2);

    register.set_value(value);

    12
}
```

The problem of course is the double borrow that happens due to '&mut self.registers.sp'. Is there any way around that without using `unsafe`, or maybe another way to do it without writing a separate function for each opcode that changes different registers?

Comment: Suppose you would pass `&mut self.registers.pc` as the argument to the function. The CPU state will be corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You can take an identifying value instead of a reference.

```rs
enum RegisterId {
    Sp,
    Pc,
    ...
}

pub fn execute_classic_instruction(&mut self, opcode: u8) -> u64 {
    match opcode {
        0x31 => self.load_word_immediate_into_reg(RegisterId::Sp),
        _ => unimplemented!(
            "Unimplemented opcode: 0x{:X} at PC=0x{:X}",
            opcode,
            self.registers.pc.value() - 1
        ),
    }
}

pub fn load_word_immediate_into_reg(&mut self, register: RegisterId) -> u64 {
    let value = self.mmu.read_word(self.registers.pc.value());
    self.registers.pc.add(2);

    // Implement Index<RegisterId> so you don't need to match every time
    self.registers[RegisterId].set_value(value);

    12
}
```

Or you can make this an unassociated function.

```rs
pub fn execute_classic_instruction(&mut self, opcode: u8) -> u64 {
    match opcode {
        0x31 => load_word_immediate_into_reg(&mut self.mmu, &mut self.registers.pc, &mut self.registers.sp),
        _ => unimplemented!(
            "Unimplemented opcode: 0x{:X} at PC=0x{:X}",
            opcode,
            self.registers.pc.value() - 1
        ),
    }
}

pub fn load_word_immediate_into_reg(mmu: &mut Mmu, pc: &mut Pc, reg: &mut Reg) -> u64 {
    let value = mmu.read_word(pc.value());
    pc.add(2);

    reg.set_value(value);

    12
}
```

The second one may be slightly more easily optimized since `pc` and `reg` are guaranteed to be separate variables. But these should be inlined enough for it not to matter. The first one is necessary if you want to pass `pc` as the register.